# Angle of attack on variable pitch propeller?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics, propulsion

For a variable pitch propeller where the angle of attack can be adjusted during flight, are the individual blades similar in design to standard propellers, with a low angle of attack at the edge of the propeller (3-6 degrees), and gradually increases towards the root (14-16 degrees); or are the propeller blades one singular angle of attack throughout the entire length of the blade? I'm presuming the blades have a differing angle of attack at the root and tip, but of a lower magnitude to prevent the root AOA on the root of the blade exceeding the critical angle?

Comment: What real blades have you checked ? Better than assuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All propellers have to have a gradually increasing twist as we get closer to the hub to maintain the same angle of attack with the relative wind at that particular position.

The reason is the change in the angle of the relative wind as we move from the tip to the root.

The relative wind is the vector sum of the airplane's speed and the speed of the point along the length of the propeller.

Relative wind tilts more toward the airplane's axial speed near the root as compared to near the tip which is more aligned with the plane of the propeller. Just compare the tangential speeds $V_t=\omega R$ the greater the R is greater Vt.

$\vec{V_r}= \vec{V_t}+\vec{V_{axial}}$

- $V_r=$ relative wind
- $V_t=$ propeller tangential speed
- $V_{axial}= $airplane speed